# Persistent Firefox extension for internal company usage

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-addon

Is there a way to have a persistent firefox extension that's only used inside a company and therefore cannot be uploaded to the firefox store?

When loading the unpacked extension to the default firefox edition, it won't stay over different browser sessions. On firefox, as far as I know, that only works with the nightly, developer and beta editions of firefox.

The extension cannot be packed and uploaded to the firefox store because it contains company information and is intended to be only used internally.

Is there a way to pack the extension so that it can be installed normally and be used like a normal extension?